# Error al usar count en una subconsulta

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tengo una consulta donde utilizo 1 subconsulta para obtener datos desde varias tablas. Y como resultado me devuelve un total de 2947 registros.

```sql
    --CONSULTA INICIAL
SELECT dniEgre,

(SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN numeRespu = 1 THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END
FROM OCL.tblDetalleRespuNumero
WHERE idPregun = '201' AND dniUsu = dniEgre collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI
ORDER BY dniEgre DESC) as Trabaja

FROM OCL.tblEgresado
WHERE dniEgre IN
(SELECT dniUsu collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI FROM OCL.tblExperiencia);
```

[image: consulta con resultado: col1 = dniEgre; col2 = SI/NO]

Ahora quiero utilizar la funcion `count` para contar los **`(SI)`** y los **`(NO)`** de mi consulta anterior.

```sql
 ---consulta para hallar cuantos si trabajan

SELECT  count ((SELECT numerespu
            FROM OCL.tblDetalleRespuNumero
            WHERE idPregun = '201' AND numeRespu=1 AND dniUsu = dniEgre collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI) as SiTrabaja)
FROM OCL.tblEgresado
WHERE dniEgre IN
(SELECT dniUsu collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI FROM OCL.tblExperiencia);
```

```sql
 ---consulta para hallar cuantos NO trabajan

SELECT  count( (SELECT numerespu
            FROM OCL.tblDetalleRespuNumero
            WHERE idPregun = '201' AND numeRespu=0 AND dniUsu = dniEgre collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI) as NoTrabaja)
FROM OCL.tblEgresado
WHERE dniEgre IN
(SELECT dniUsu collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI FROM OCL.tblExperiencia);
```

Pero al utilizar `count`  en las subconsultas me sale este error:

> 'count' no es un nombre de función integrada reconocido.

Espero me puedan ayudar con este error, para poder contar los registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple para contarlo modificando lo menos tu query sería algo así

```
SELECT a.Trabaja, COUNT(1) AS Cuenta
FROM 
(
        SELECT dniEgre,
        (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN numeRespu = 1 THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END
        FROM OCL.tblDetalleRespuNumero
        WHERE idPregun = '201' AND dniUsu = dniEgre collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI
        ORDER BY dniEgre DESC) as Trabaja
        FROM OCL.tblEgresado
        WHERE dniEgre IN
        (SELECT dniUsu collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI FROM OCL.tblExperiencia);
) a
GROUP BY a.Trabaja
```

El código dentro de la subconsulta a es el que has incluido arriba. El campo Cuenta te dará el número de registros por cada SI o NO.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes conseguir las cuentas para los `SI` y los `NO` de un solo usando un `count` condicional de esta manera:

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT dniEgre,

    (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN numeRespu = 1 THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END
    FROM OCL.tblDetalleRespuNumero
    WHERE idPregun = '201' AND dniUsu = dniEgre collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI
    ORDER BY dniEgre DESC) as Trabaja

    FROM OCL.tblEgresado
    WHERE dniEgre IN
    (SELECT dniUsu collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI FROM OCL.tblExperiencia)
)
select si_count = count(case when Trabaja = 'SI' then 'X' end),
       no_count = count(case when Trabaja = 'NO' then 'X' end),
       total_count = count(*)
  from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cierra el `count` antes de la consulta

```
    select count(1) 
      from (SELECT numerespu 
              FROM OCL.tblDetalleRespuNumero 
             WHERE idPregun = '201' 
               AND numeRespu=1
               AND dniUsu = dniEgre collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI as SiTrabaja
              FROM OCL.tblEgresado 
             WHERE dniEgre IN (SELECT dniUsu collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AI 
                               FROM OCL.tblExperiencia)) x
```

He copiado el query que pusiste de ejemplo, solo para demostrarte donde debe de ir el count()

Comment: No sabía que se podía formatear el código así, gracias por el consejo